# How to get column values of csv file in pandas or other methods in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have .csv file which looks like this:

```
id,product
1,car
1,phone
2,tv
```

I want to get all rows which match the certain condition e.g:
If the id==1, and product value contains letter "a", print all matched rows (e.g '1,car' will be printed). I know this would be better to work with database but I need to work with csv file.

I tried with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('products.csv')

for value_i in df.id:
    for value_p in df.product:
         if (value_i==2 and "a" in value_p):
             print(value_i, value_p)
```

But I don't get a good result. If someone can give me a hint how to access values of a columns I would be thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and for check values in strings use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df1 = df[(df['id'] == 1) & (df['product'].str.contains('a'))]
print (df1)
   id product
0   1     car
```

Detail:

```
print ((df['id'] == 1) & (df['product'].str.contains('a')))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```